# .NET Web API: Get Route Value for a given Method

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

It is possible to return the Route based on the name of a given method within .NET Core?

For example

The below is a HttpGet request and is accessible on "apple/all/expanded"

```
       [Route("apple/all/expanded")]
       [HttpGet]
       public object GetAllApplesExpanded()
       {

           return apples;

       }
```

Question is whether it is possible to get the value of the route ("apple/all/expanded") in **another class or controller** simply by passing in the name of the method (GetAllApplesExpanded) and not hardcoding the route value in?

Comment: What if there are multiple classes or controllers with the same method name? You will probably need to know which class or controller it belongs to.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the assumption here is that I have that information to hand. So I can pass in ControllerName.MethodName to get the route value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code in other controller.

```
 Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var e = asm.GetTypes()
               .Where(type => typeof(Yourcontroller)
               .IsAssignableFrom(type))
               .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods()).Where(c => c.Name == "GetAllApplesExpanded").FirstOrDefault()
               .CustomAttributes.Where(c => c.AttributeType.Name == "RouteAttribute").FirstOrDefault()
               .ConstructorArguments.FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Test result:

[image]